# How do I alter the items listed in an AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In my app the user can add new cities. This should go as follows:

1. Presses the 'add city' button from the menu.
2. Selects a province from the list (AlertDialog) that appears.
3. Selects a city from the list that is created based on the selected province.

The province dialog will always be the same, so I made the city dialog a separate dialog.
The problem is that since onCreateDialog() is only called the first time a city is added, I can't figure out how to adjust this list based on the province selected. addItems() is a method of AlertDialog.builder, which isn't of much use to me in onPrepareDialog as far as I can tell.

How do I alter the list of items in the dialog each time it is called (and update the onClickListener accordingly?

Edit: I've added the code that I have so far. There are 2 major issues with my current implementation:

1. The city dialog (SelectLocationDialog) looks completely different from the province dialog. I can't figure out how to make them look identical (I'm using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 for the city dialog for now).
2. There is no onClickListener for the city dialog, so it doesn't really do much of anything.

   ```
   @Override
   protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = null;

       switch (id) {

           case DIALOG_SELECT_PROVINCE:
               return SelectProvinceDialog.create(this);

           case DIALOG_SELECT_LOCATION:
               return SelectLocationDialog.create(this);

           default:
               return null;
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {

       switch (id) {

           case DIALOG_SELECT_LOCATION:
               // looks up all cities/sites in the province selected in the
               // previous dialog
               siteList = new XmlSiteListReader(this);
               siteList.findSitesByProvince(Province.valueOf(
                       Province.getAbbreviatedName(selectedProvince)));
               String[] sites = siteList.siteNames();

               ListView siteListView = new ListView(this);
               ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> siteListAdapter = 
                       new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, 
                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sites);
               siteListView.setAdapter(siteListAdapter);
               dialog.setContentView(siteListView);
       }
   }



   /**
    * A dialog that allows the user to select a province/region from which to add
    * locations to watch.
    * 
    * @author Dean Morin
    */
   public class SelectProvinceDialog {

       private static final String[] PROVINCES;
       static {
           PROVINCES = new String[Province.values().length];
           Province[] provinces = Province.values();
           for (int i = 0; i < provinces.length; i++) {
               PROVINCES[i] = provinces[i].getFullName();
           }
       }

       /**
        * Creates the 'Select Province' dialog window.
        * 
        * @param context The context for this dialog.
        * @return The constructed dialog.
        */
       public static AlertDialog create(final Context context) {
           AlertDialog.Builder selectProv = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
           selectProv.setTitle("Select Province");
           selectProv.setItems(PROVINCES, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                   ((WeatherWatch) context).setSelectedProvince(PROVINCES[item]);
                   ((Activity) context)
                           .showDialog(WeatherWatch.DIALOG_SELECT_LOCATION, null);
               }
           });
           return selectProv.create();
       }
   }


   public class SelectLocationDialog {

       /**
        * Creates the 'Select Location' dialog window.
        * 
        * @param context The context for this dialog.
        * @return The constructed dialog.
        */
       public static AlertDialog create(final Context context) {
           AlertDialog.Builder selectLoc = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
           return selectLoc.create();
       }    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

onPrepareDialog is the place you'll be able to change the values of the list. I've done something similar before. Post your code if you need help to write it.

Comment: I've added what I have so far, as well as the 2 reasons why it doesn't  really work.